# Guice: Injecting Interceptors in ServletModule

Tags: java, guice, vaadin

I am trying to inject an Interceptor with a Vaadin Application instance created by Guice. 
I've followed the documentation for Vaadin-Guice integration in the [Vaadin Wiki](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Integrating%20Vaadin%20with%20Guice%202.0?p_r_p_185834411_title=Integrating%2520Vaadin%2520with%2520Guice%25202.0) and 
the documenation on Interceptor DI in the [Guice Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AOP#Injecting_Interceptors):

```
public class RecruitmentServletConfig extends GuiceServletContextListener {

    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector() {

        ServletModule servletModule = new ServletModule() {

            @Override
            protected void configureServlets() {
                ...
                bind(Application.class).to(RecruitmentApplication.class).in(ServletScopes.SESSION);
                SecurityGuard securityGuard = new SecurityGuard();
                requestInjection(securityGuard);
                bindInterceptor(Matchers.subclassesOf(CustomComponent.class), Matchers.annotatedWith(AllowedRoles.class), securityGuard);
            }
        };
        return Guice.createInjector(servletModule);
    }
}
```

The SecurityGuard interceptor:

```
public class SecurityGuard implements MethodInterceptor {
    @Inject private Application application;

    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        AllowedRoles allowedRoles = invocation.getMethod().getAnnotation(AllowedRoles.class);
        if (((User) application.getUser()).hasRole(allowedRoles.value())) {
            return invocation.proceed(); 
        } else {
            return null;
        }
}
```

However, I get an OutOfScopeException on server startup:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class de.embl.eicat.recruit.ioc.RecruitmentServletConfig
com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:
1) Error in custom provider, com.google.inject.OutOfScopeException: Cannot access scoped object. Either we are not currently inside an HTTP Servlet request, or you may have forgotten to apply com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter as a servlet filter for this request.
at recruit.ioc.RecruitmentServletConfig$1.configureServlets(RecruitmentServletConfig.java:86)
```

Comment: Note on the scope of Application.class: Application instances need to be created for each new user session (hence .in(ServletScopes.SESSION). However, the configure() / configureServlets() method is called at server startup before any user sessions are created, which I guess explains the OutOfScopeException. This being true, where should requestInjection(securityGuard) be invoked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it work if you wrap your `Application` in a `Provider`?

```
public class SecurityGuard implements MethodInterceptor {
    @Inject private Provider<Application> application;

    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
       AllowedRoles allowedRoles = invocation.getMethod().getAnnotation(AllowedRoles.class);
        if (((User) application.get().getUser()).hasRole(allowedRoles.value())) {
            return invocation.proceed(); 
        } else {
            return null;
        }
}
```

Comment: This is the right solution. By using a provider instead of a direct reference, Guice will invoke the provider *each time* the application is needed, instead of trying to do it up front. Presuming the provider will be invoked *during* a vaadin session callback, it succeeds by pulling the application from the session scope, which has already been set up on the stack.